# The element type 'bool' can't be asigned to the map value type 'Widget Function'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Esto sería el main donde tengo separadas varias cosas, acá yo quería poner cada página con `Navigator.PushNamed` pero no me deja por ese error.

```
import 'package:componentes/src/pages/home_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Componentes APP',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
       // home: HomePage(),
          routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
            '/'   : (BuildContext context) ==> HomePage(),  // ACÁ ME DA EL ERROR
          },
        );
  }
}
```

Código de mi homepage, donde creo yo que está el error, aunque creo también que es una línea de código que hay que cambiar: creo que es la página donde está el error.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:componentes/src/providers/menu_provider.dart';
import 'package:componentes/src/utils/icono_string_util.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Componentes'),
      ),
      body: _lista(),
    );
  }

  Widget _lista() {
    // menuProvider.cargarData().then((opciones)

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: menuProvider.cargarData(),
      initialData: [],
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
        return ListView(
          children: _listaItems(snapshot.data, context),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _listaItems(List<dynamic> data, BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> opciones = [];

    data.forEach((opt) {
      final widgetTemp = ListTile(
          title: Text(opt['texto']),
          leading: getIcon(opt['icon']),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, opt['ruta']);

            // final route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AlertPage());
            // Navigator.push(context, route);
          });

      opciones..add(widgetTemp)..add(Divider());
    });

    return opciones;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es que estas igualando la función anónima en la que creas la ruta al widget `HomePage()`

En tu codigo esta asi:

```
'/': (BuildContext context) ==> HomePage()
```

Y deberia ser asi:

```
'/': (BuildContext context) => HomePage()
```

Por eso el error dice que *no podes asignar un tipo `bool` en un lugar donde se espera un `WidgetFunction`*